# React-native packager does not detect changes made on host computer when running in vagrant VM's synced folder

Tags: vagrant, react-native, watchman

I am running a vagrant VM on OSX.  I have set up a synced folder for the VM in which I run react-native packager. When I edit files on my host computer, the packager does not automatically detect that the file has changed. This works if I edit the file directly in the VM. I have checked that the file actually changes on the VM when I edit it on my host computer. Has anybody had the same problem or figured out a solution how to get this working?

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm having similar issue, not with react, but watchman in general.

Comment: No. Didn't put that much effort into investigating it afterwards :/